# Does anyone have any information about the file format of a .jdb2 (Jeb Decompiler's Project file) or how to fix one that is corrupted?

Tags: decompiler, jeb

I have a .jdb2 JebDecompiler project file which is corrupted and JebDecompiler can not open it. Any information about .jdb2 file format could be useful for me in order to read data from it and even fix it. If you can share any information about this file format it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to contact support, it would probably be the fastest way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that.